# How to send message to unsaved number using Telegram API(Telethon)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I'm using Telethon's send_message function to send messages to various numbers.
Problem that I'm facing is I can send messages to numbers that are in my contact list, but when I'm sending message to unsaved number I'm getting an error **"ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "+XXXXXXXXXXXX"**

```
from telethon import TelegramClient

api_id = xxxxx
api_hash = 'xxxxx'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    await client.send_message('+XYZXYZXYZXYZ', 'Hello, friend!')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: You can only send messages via phone number if the user is in your contacts.

Answer (score 0):

it's the new telegram limit about get numbers of accounts

[image: privacy setting]

if it's `Nobody` you can't find it by number if you have not this in your contacts before

Comment: Changed it to everybody in both receivers and senders telegram account but still not working.

Comment: so u have to save it in your contacts then try again

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make telethon aware of all the entities at least once:
For this use:

```
dialogs = await client.get_dialogs()
```

After this get the entity represented by the mobile number using the command:

```
entity = await client.get_entity(<mobile_num>)
```

Now you can use the entity to send message

```
await client.send_message(entity, 'Hello, friend!')
```

For more info have a look at this : [Telethon Entities](http://sktechhub.com/?redirect=true&url=https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/concepts/entities.html)

Comment: Now I'm getting same error in **entity = await client.get_entity(<mobile_num>)**

Comment: have you initiated any conv. with that number yet?

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answer works for me so after lot of effort I got the solution of the problem.
It is not possible to send message to a telegram user without saving their number.
To overcome this problem first we have to save the number by these lines of code:

**Note:** You have to downgrade your telethon to 0.19 for this just run ***pip install telethon==0.19***

```
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=guest_phone_number,\
first_name="first_name", last_name="last_name")
result = client.invoke(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
```

Here is full working code:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import AddChatUserRequest
from telethon.tl.types import InputPhoneContact
from telethon.tl.functions.contacts import ImportContactsRequest

api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
phone_number = '+XXXXXXXXXXXX' #sender's phone number
guest_phone_number='+XXXXXXXXXXXX' #recievers phone number

client = TelegramClient('session_name',
                api_id,
                api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

# ---------------------------------------
# add user to contact
contact = InputPhoneContact(client_id=0, phone=guest_phone_number,\ 
first_name="user", last_name=" ")
result = client.invoke(ImportContactsRequest([contact]))
# ---------------------------------------
# send message to reciever
client.send_message(result.users[0], 'Hello, friend!')
```